# Ember.js 2.0 - modifying property twice in a single render deprecation warning

Tags: ember.js, deprecated

I'm developing a application with the current Ember 2.0 beta release (beta 1), and have started to see this deprecation warning:

> You modified XXX twice in a single render. This was unreliable in Ember 1.x and will be removed in Ember 2.0

It looks like the offenders are computed properties that are being recalculated multiple times because their dependent key(s) are being updated multiple times in a single run loop. However the stack traces for the deprecations don't lead back to any of my application code, and I thought this was something Ember should already be silently taking care of for me anyway.

Is this something I need to actively fix in my app code before updating to v2.0 final when its released, or is it just more of an 'internal' deprecation notice? If I do need to make changes, is there any common anti-patterns or gotchas I should look out for that would cause this error?

Comment: Maybe this tackles your issue as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461366/you-modified-twice-in-a-single-render/31476826

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you missed it, this should be fixed in master: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11519